# Use django-import-export with class based views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I want to use `django-import-export` with class based views.

In the docs at https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html I see an example of exporting as csv

```
>>> dataset = BookResource().export()
>>> print dataset.csv
id,name,author,author_email,imported,published,price,categories
2,Some book,1,,0,2012-12-05,8.85,1
```

but which class based view should I use if I want to return an Excel file? Just `View`?

Comment: Is there a necessity to use `django-import-export` . You can use `xlwt ` to write in xls files.

Comment: May be this can help you - http://djangotricks.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-export-data-as-excel.html

Comment: It looks like `xlwt` is not compatible with Python 3.4

Answer (score 14):

Jamgreen,

Based on implementation at https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export and considering a model "Country" as example with name and abreviation atributes:

First, define at the end of Country models file the Resource:

```
class CountryResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
```

Then, implement the class based views:

```
class CountryExport(View):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs ):
        dataset = CountryResource().export()
        response = HttpResponse(dataset.csv, content_type="csv")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.csv'
        return response


class CountryImport(View):
    model = Country
    from_encoding = "utf-8"

    #: import / export formats
    DEFAULT_FORMATS = (
        base_formats.CSV,
        base_formats.XLS,
        base_formats.TSV,
        base_formats.ODS,
        base_formats.JSON,
        base_formats.YAML,
        base_formats.HTML,
    )
    formats = DEFAULT_FORMATS
    #: template for import view
    import_template_name = 'Country/import.html'
    resource_class = None

    def get_import_formats(self):
        """
        Returns available import formats.
        """
        return [f for f in self.formats if f().can_import()]

    def get_resource_class(self):
        if not self.resource_class:
            return modelresource_factory(self.model)
        else:
            return self.resource_class

    def get_import_resource_class(self):
        """
        Returns ResourceClass to use for import.
        """
        return self.get_resource_class()

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs ):
        '''
        Perform a dry_run of the import to make sure the import will not
        result in errors.  If there where no error, save the user
        uploaded file to a local temp file that will be used by
        'process_import' for the actual import.
        '''
        resource = self.get_import_resource_class()()

        context = {}

        import_formats = self.get_import_formats()
        form = ImportForm(import_formats,
                          self.request.POST or None,
                          self.request.FILES or None)

        if self.request.POST and form.is_valid():
            input_format = import_formats[
                int(form.cleaned_data['input_format'])
            ]()
            import_file = form.cleaned_data['import_file']
            # first always write the uploaded file to disk as it may be a
            # memory file or else based on settings upload handlers
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as uploaded_file:
                for chunk in import_file.chunks():
                    uploaded_file.write(chunk)

            # then read the file, using the proper format-specific mode
            with open(uploaded_file.name,
                      input_format.get_read_mode()) as uploaded_import_file:
                # warning, big files may exceed memory
                data = uploaded_import_file.read()
                if not input_format.is_binary() and self.from_encoding:
                    data = force_text(data, self.from_encoding)
                dataset = input_format.create_dataset(data)
                result = resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True,
                                              raise_errors=False)

            context['result'] = result

            if not result.has_errors():
                context['confirm_form'] = ConfirmImportForm(initial={
                    'import_file_name': os.path.basename(uploaded_file.name),
                    'input_format': form.cleaned_data['input_format'],
                })

        context['form'] = form
        context['opts'] = self.model._meta
        context['fields'] = [f.column_name for f in resource.get_fields()]

        return TemplateResponse(self.request, [self.import_template_name], context)


    def post(self, *args, **kwargs ):
        '''
        Perform a dry_run of the import to make sure the import will not
        result in errors.  If there where no error, save the user
        uploaded file to a local temp file that will be used by
        'process_import' for the actual import.
        '''
        resource = self.get_import_resource_class()()

        context = {}

        import_formats = self.get_import_formats()
        form = ImportForm(import_formats,
                          self.request.POST or None,
                          self.request.FILES or None)

        if self.request.POST and form.is_valid():
            input_format = import_formats[
                int(form.cleaned_data['input_format'])
            ]()
            import_file = form.cleaned_data['import_file']
            # first always write the uploaded file to disk as it may be a
            # memory file or else based on settings upload handlers
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as uploaded_file:
                for chunk in import_file.chunks():
                    uploaded_file.write(chunk)

            # then read the file, using the proper format-specific mode
            with open(uploaded_file.name,
                      input_format.get_read_mode()) as uploaded_import_file:
                # warning, big files may exceed memory
                data = uploaded_import_file.read()
                if not input_format.is_binary() and self.from_encoding:
                    data = force_text(data, self.from_encoding)
                dataset = input_format.create_dataset(data)
                result = resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True,
                                              raise_errors=False)

            context['result'] = result

            if not result.has_errors():
                context['confirm_form'] = ConfirmImportForm(initial={
                    'import_file_name': os.path.basename(uploaded_file.name),
                    'input_format': form.cleaned_data['input_format'],
                })

        context['form'] = form
        context['opts'] = self.model._meta
        context['fields'] = [f.column_name for f in resource.get_fields()]

        return TemplateResponse(self.request, [self.import_template_name], context)

class CountryProcessImport(View):
    model = Country
    from_encoding = "utf-8"

    #: import / export formats
    DEFAULT_FORMATS = (
        base_formats.CSV,
        base_formats.XLS,
        base_formats.TSV,
        base_formats.ODS,
        base_formats.JSON,
        base_formats.YAML,
        base_formats.HTML,
    )
    formats = DEFAULT_FORMATS
    #: template for import view
    import_template_name = 'Country/import.html'
    resource_class = None



    def get_import_formats(self):
        """
        Returns available import formats.
        """
        return [f for f in self.formats if f().can_import()]

    def get_resource_class(self):
        if not self.resource_class:
            return modelresource_factory(self.model)
        else:
            return self.resource_class

    def get_import_resource_class(self):
        """
        Returns ResourceClass to use for import.
        """
        return self.get_resource_class()

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs ):
        '''
        Perform the actual import action (after the user has confirmed he
    wishes to import)
        '''
        opts = self.model._meta
        resource = self.get_import_resource_class()()

        confirm_form = ConfirmImportForm(self.request.POST)
        if confirm_form.is_valid():
            import_formats = self.get_import_formats()
            input_format = import_formats[
                int(confirm_form.cleaned_data['input_format'])
            ]()
            import_file_name = os.path.join(
                tempfile.gettempdir(),
                confirm_form.cleaned_data['import_file_name']
            )
            import_file = open(import_file_name, input_format.get_read_mode())
            data = import_file.read()
            if not input_format.is_binary() and self.from_encoding:
                data = force_text(data, self.from_encoding)
            dataset = input_format.create_dataset(data)

            result = resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False,
                                 raise_errors=True)

            # Add imported objects to LogEntry
            ADDITION = 1
            CHANGE = 2
            DELETION = 3
            logentry_map = {
                RowResult.IMPORT_TYPE_NEW: ADDITION,
                RowResult.IMPORT_TYPE_UPDATE: CHANGE,
                RowResult.IMPORT_TYPE_DELETE: DELETION,
            }
            content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model).pk
            '''
            for row in result:
                LogEntry.objects.log_action(
                    user_id=request.user.pk,
                    content_type_id=content_type_id,
                    object_id=row.object_id,
                    object_repr=row.object_repr,
                    action_flag=logentry_map[row.import_type],
                    change_message="%s through import_export" % row.import_type,
                )
            '''
            success_message = _('Import finished')
            messages.success(self.request, success_message)
            import_file.close()

            url = reverse('%s_list' % (str(opts.app_label).lower()))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

the template import.html has the following code:

```
<h1>{% trans "Importar" %} {{ opts.app_label }}</h1>

{% if confirm_form %}
  <form action="{% url "process_import" %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ confirm_form.as_p }}
    <p>
      {% trans "Below is a preview of data to be imported. If you are satisfied with the results, click 'Confirm import'" %}
    </p>
    <div class="submit-row">
      <input type="submit" class="btn" name="confirm" value="{% trans "Confirm import" %}">
    </div>
  </form>

{% else %}
  <form action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" id="{{ opts.module_name }}_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <p>
      {% trans "This importer will import the following fields: " %}
      {% for f in fields  %}
        {% if forloop.counter0 %}
        , 
        {% endif %}
        <tt>{{ f }}</tt>
      {% endfor %}
    </p>

    <fieldset class="module aligned">
      {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-row">
          {{ field.errors }}

          {{ field.label_tag }}

          {{ field }}

          {% if field.field.help_text %}
          <p class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>

    <div class="submit-row">
      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="{% trans "Submit" %}">
    </div>
  </form>
{% endif %}

{% if result %}
    {% if result.has_errors %}
        <h2>{% trans "Errors" %}</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for error in result.base_errors  %}
                <li>{{ error.error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for line, errors in result.row_errors %}
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>
                      {% trans "Line number" %}: {{ line }} - {{ error.error }}
                      <div class="traceback">{{ error.traceback|linebreaks }}</div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <h2>
            {% trans "Preview" %}
        </h2>
        <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            {% for field in fields %}
              <th>{{ field }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for row in result.rows %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                {% if row.import_type == 'new' %}
                    {% trans "New" %}
                {% elif row.import_type == 'skip' %}
                    {% trans "Skipped" %}
                {% elif row.import_type == 'delete' %}
                    {% trans "Delete" %}
                {% elif row.import_type == 'update' %}
                    {% trans "Update" %}
                {% endif %}
                </td>
              {% for field in row.diff %}
              <td>
                  {{ field }}
              </td>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

and the urls.py should contain:

```
#export
url(r'export/$', login_required(CountryExport.as_view()), name='country_export'),

#import
url(r'import/$', login_required(CountryImport.as_view()), name='country_import'),
url(r'process_import/$',     login_required(CountryProcessImport.as_view()), name='process_import'),
```

Comment: Excuse me sir. I am trying his approach, I think I almost got it. However, I am getting this error: `AttributeError
Exception Value:  

'list' object has no attribute 'get'`, when I click the submit button. I would appreciate any suggestion, what's going on?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried for a long time to make this work in a FormView without no ConfirmForm, but I don't know how to make the form_valid() so it works.

Comment: I'm also getting `'list' object has no attribute 'get'` after adding a ModelChoiceField to the form. It's related to the import formats which I think get passed to the form as initial data on the get request. `form.data` is the list of formats, but the error occurs on `self.field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.form.data, self.form.files, self.html_name)` which obviously expects a `dict()`

Comment: I edited the answer added urls and view class that process import. I hope it helps solve the error... Regards

Answer (score 2):

I've done the exact same thing today. I tried to make the view fairly generic and allow values to be passed through in the URL so it is a little more complex than simply returning an XLS file.

But anyway, this was my approach;

```
class PlaceResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Place


class ExportPlacesView(View):
    model = Place

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        client_name = str(self.client).replace(' ', '_').lower()
        if 'query' in kwargs:

            if kwargs['query'] == u'complete':
                complete_runners = Place.objects.filter(
                    ~models.Q(runner__completed_on=None),
                    console=self.console).values_list(
                    'client',
                    flat=True).distinct()

                dataset = PlaceResource().export(
                    Place.objects.filter(
                        console=self.console, client=self.client,
                        runner__in=complete_runners
                    )
                )
                filename = '{}_completed_runners'.format(client_name)
        else:
            dataset = PlaceResource().export(Place.objects.filter(
                console=self.console, client=self.client,
            ))
            filename = '{}_Runners'.format(client_name)

        export_type = kwargs['format']
        _dataset_methods = {
            'csv': dataset.csv,
            'xls': dataset.xls
        }
        response = HttpResponse(
            _dataset_methods[export_type], content_type=export_type
        )
        response[
            'Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={filename}.{ext}'.format(
                filename=filename,
                ext=export_type
            )
        return response
```