# How to upload all rows in an excel file into django model with xlrd

Tags: python, django, excel, model, xlrd

How can I modify this code to accept to upload all lines of data in the excel sheet provided? Curerently it only picks the values in row 2, i.e after the headers.

```
def UploadTeacherView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTeachersForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            excel_file = request.FILES['file']
            fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
            try:
                with os.fdopen(fd, 'wb') as tmp:
                    tmp.write(excel_file.read())
                book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
                sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
                obj=TeacherData(
                    school_id = sheet.cell_value(rowx=1, colx=1),
                    code = sheet.cell_value(rowx=1, colx=2),
                    first_name = sheet.cell_value(rowx=1, colx=3),
                    last_name = sheet.cell_value(rowx=1, colx=4),
                    email = sheet.cell_value(rowx=1, colx=5),
                    phone = sheet.cell_value(rowx=1, colx=6),
                )
                obj.save()
            finally:
                os.remove(path)
        else:
            message='Invalid Entries'
    else:
        form = NewTeachersForm()
    return render(request,'new_teacher.html', {'form':form,'message':message})
```

Comment: Why not use something that's built for uploading (or event exporting) data from a number of file formats? https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Very good of you @markwalker. How would it fit in my code,please?

Comment: Have a read through this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008820/use-django-import-export-with-class-based-views

Comment: Answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66983150/how-would-i-manage-to-upload-al-the-rows-with-the-django-view/66993078#66993078